# Why different sizes of a text are in different columns of a table in mobile Chrome and Chromium-browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The mobile Chrome and similar Chromium-browsers have a very strange behaviour.
They shows first group of columns with small size, and second group with big size.
The problem is on any phones.
A desktop Chrome and other browsers show the content normally.
I have checked my code by a html and css validator.
The results are here:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdz4all.ru%2F

The html and css are here.

```css
table {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 10px solid rgb(240, 240, 245);
    border-left: 10px solid rgb(240, 240, 245);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.dayWeek {
    color: #1d1d1b;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: NotoSerif-Bold,serif;
}

.date {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    color: #1d1d1b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.subject {
    color: brown;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: Roboto-bold,sans-serif;
}
.lesson_content {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    color: #7d7e86;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
}

.homework {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    color: #7d7e86;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> <span class="dayWeek">Понедельник</span>
                <br>
                <span class="date">21.10</span>
            </th>
            <th> <span class="dayWeek">Вторник</span>
                <br>
                <span class="date">22.10</span>
            </th>
            <th> <span class="dayWeek">Среда</span>
                <br>
                <span class="date">23.10</span>
            </th>
            <th> <span class="dayWeek">Четверг</span>
                <br>
                <span class="date">24.10</span>
            </th>
            <th> <span class="dayWeek">Пятница</span>
                <br>
                <span class="date">25.10</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <span class="subject">Иностранный язык (английский):</span>
                <br>
                <span class="lesson_content" style="display: inline;">Прямые и непрямые вопросы</span>
                <br class="br" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="homework">Дз: с 42 у3, 4, 5</span>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span class="subject">Русский язык:</span>
                <br>
                <span class="lesson_content" style="display: inline;">Типы сложных предложений. Средства связи между частями предложения</span>
                <br class="br" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="homework">Дз: Подготовиться к тестированию</span>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span class="subject">Литература:</span>
                <br>
                <span class="lesson_content" style="display: inline;">«Не образумлюсь, виноват…» Анализ 4 действия</span>
                <br class="br" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="homework">Дз: 3 действие</span>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span class="subject">Литература:</span>
                <br>
                <span class="lesson_content" style="display: inline;">РР И.А.Гончаров «Мильон терзаний». Работа с критической литературой</span>
                <br class="br" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="homework">Дз: 4 действие</span>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td> <span class="subject">Алгебра:</span>
                <br>
                <span class="lesson_content" style="display: inline;">Область определения функции</span>
                <br class="br" style="display: inline;">
                <span class="homework">Дз: вариант огэ</span>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[image: a table]

Comment: Provide your HTML with CSS.

Comment: I tried your snippet both on desktop and on mobile but could not reproduce it. Furthermore: opening the URL you provided shows different content (possibly because I am not logged in). I'm guessing that also the W3C Validator looks at it while not being logged in, so the validation result means nothing if logging in is a requirement.

Comment: @PeterB I have just switched off the vkontakte. You can go again. I have also replaced the tages <br> and <span> to the tages p. But it does not fix the problem

Comment: Can see the content now, and can reproduce on mobile. But can't find a direct cause... Try if it helps to add `width:20%` to the `td, th` selector (since everything is in 5 columns, I guess for weekdays). And/or try using `display:block` for the `<div id="content">`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of the problem. I just added in the tag `<head>` one line:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
But I must to say that the HTML markup can be different on a desktop computer and on a phone.